# Eclipse Android Running App on device. Nothing happens

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, device

I am just beginning to use Eclipse for Android applications. After updating my Android SDK i can't run my projects on device anymore. It says "Installing app.apk..." but nothing happens. Installing my app with adb without eclipse works, where could be an Issue? I reinstalled SDK and Eclipse twice.

Comment: try to kill adb server and then restart it again through cmd.

Comment: i tried. with adb through cmd it works, but not in eclipse

Comment: Strange thing is, that i can run the project, it doesn't get installed on my phone, but i can save the built .apk-file and install this file with adb throught cmd.

Comment: it can be the problem of your phone try restarting your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try unistalling the application from the phone before re-installing it.  Also make sure you have the option to allow non-market apps checked in your phone settings --> applications.

Comment: I tried it with many differnet and new Apps (including standart test apps). I checked that option. The strange thing is it worked before SDK and AVD update on the same phone before and is still working just with adb.

Comment: If you just update SDK and AVD i would try restarting eclipse or restarting your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Is it getting stuck at a particular percentage? If that is the case, the solution was to keep the virtual device running before you attempt to run the project.

Comment: Im not running it on a virtual device

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my computer. Android sdk on eclipse doesn't work well with windows x64.
So to launch the application you have to kill the adb process. Wait that adb restart and launch one more time.